# Introduction to number theory

Tags: number-theory, computer-algebra

What is the best book for a beginner in Introduction to number theory?

I am new to this field and getting deeper into cryptography, so I think reading some intro books about number theory can be of help.

Comment: A reference request like yours is too broad for Stack Exchange -- you ask for a survey of a whole research area! You need to narrow your focus considerably before a question of reasonable scope appears, and you also need to include criteria that allow to say that and why one answer is better than another (why is not "any book on the topic" an answer?). Try talking to your advisor(s), search with [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=some+query) and check out [this guide to better (re)searches](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13594/1419) on [academia.SE].

Comment: Dear Raphael, the question I believe is more than clear and direct and is not too broad. This forum is called 'Stack Exchange', which is what what precisely my questions begs. An exchange of ideas. No one, as far as I can see (hear, sense and smell) has asked for a survey of a whole research area. Putting the question on hold is a big sign of disrespect and arrogance.

Comment: Your individual opinion notwithstanding we have certain community standards, and your question fails to meet them. As a moderator my task is to uphold said standards, so going all ad hominem in my direction is futile. If you take issue with my decision, feel free to flag for reopening (hint: you may want to heed my above comment first) or raise the issue on [meta].

Comment: tony9099, Raphael is exactly right. Our moderators merely enforce standards and policies established by the community. I realize that if you're new to the site you might not be familiar with some of these policies. If you have questions about site policies, you're welcome to visit [meta] to learn more. But please treat our moderators with respect. They have a thankless job, but they are vital to the success of the site. They volunteer their time and I for one am very grateful for their work. Rest assured that they're not on a power trip; they're merely enforcing policies set by the community.

Comment: Dear D.W nobody is disrespecting anyone. How dare you insult me such cheap accusations. I can not find any word of disrespect in my comment. If you do, that is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go deeper into cryptography and number theory, then of course you start here: [Neal Koblitz, A Course in Number Theory and Cryptography](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-0-387-94293-3).

Comment: Thanks. I am reading now Applied Cryptography by Bruce Schneier. It is okay, but does not get deep inside the maths a lot.

Comment: Well, that's probably why it's called _Applied Cryptography_. Koblitz starts with two chapters of pure number theory, and then goes on to build cryptography upon it. So if you want to understand the math part, use that book. There are certainly other books with more number theory to go into once you're done with that.

Comment: Okay John. I will do as you suggest. I think its a good way to start building up some notions about crypto.

Comment: Good luck! I enjoyed the book very much.

Comment: And why do you recommend this book over (all) others?

Comment: I read all others, and all the other books there will ever be! No, but seriously, the op asked for a number theory book, while coming from cryptography. I don't think this question is as broad as you stated it is. And while there certainly are other books, I would specifically recommend _this_ one, because I liked it, because it finds the right balance in difficulty and length and surely for other reasons too. I can elaborate my answer a bit more if you want to, but maybe you should open the question again.

Comment: @Raphael PS I disagree with your opinion that this question is too broad. It might be helpful if the op does add some more criteria on what she/he would like (length/difficulty/whatever), but I don't see a reason to close this question radically.

Comment: This is how we have been dealing with unspecific book requests (cf [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/640/98) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/957/98)). If you think it's the wrong policy, you are invited to post on [meta], too.

Comment: "Book on number theory, cryptography background": I don't think that's unspecific at all. Btw, your "we" seems to be "I".

Comment: I think it is a big mistake to appoint @Raphael an admin to manage such stuff. From his reactions I can understand he is immature and defensive. I do not think an amazing society like the Computer Science Society should be left in the hands of such man, as all they do is push away people who want to be involved away. I would recommend dismissing him from his duties.

Comment: @tony9099 First of all, please avoid insults. And I am quite sure that you don't know whether Raphael is immature or defensive, so don't claim so. If you want to change some policies, or if you think there should be different moderators, then start a discussion on the meta. Without insults, prettyplease.

Comment: Btw @tony9099, I do think that personal insults will push more people away than questions that were closed a little too fast.

Comment: @john_leo, there are no insults. read well my friend. I take total responsibility of what I say, and I think I am free to say/claim what I want to say. Moreover, you do not have the right to tell me what to say or no. Kindly, mind your own business and let me take care of mine. Btw, thanks for the book, I already have it :)

Comment: Hm, it might only be me, but I find "immature" insulting.